# Extracting words from certain lines using regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to find words in a text file using powershell and print them into another file.
Those words do not really have any properties that would distinguish them among other words except for the number of the line where each o the word is located. I need data about medications for my study and the data is copied form webpages that look similar and the names of the medicine are printed in the same lines every time. This are lines scattered all over text file, containing a single word each one of them, like so many others in there unfortunately.

Here is a sample text and in this sample I'm interested in copying the names of the medications which in this case are: Amoxicillin, Clindamycin, Azithromycin (lines 6,17,28) and so on, roughly 350 pages, 20 drug names on each...

```
adm inj
500mg
Finished
adm inj
no 
Amoxicillin 6
company logo 
medication Photo
1
1

adm inj
500mg
Finished
adm inj
no 
Clindamycin 17
company logo 
medication Photo
23
22

adm inj
128mg
Available
adm inj
yes 
Azithromycin 28
company logo 
medication Photo
1
1
```

I am not a pro coder but what I did was some research and tried this to extract lines with single words (consisting at least two letters - bit proud of my self there) :

```
$path = Resolve-Path unsoted.txt | Select -Expand Path
(Get-Content $path)| Select-String -pattern "^(\w+[a-z]{2})$" -AllMatches | Out-File medications.txt
```

Of course the result is all wrong because of other unwanted lines with unrelated single words, I also found "Select-Object" cdmlet but to me it has no parameters that would be suitable for my purpose. I do know how to upload the data and save it, I also understand that PowerShell uses RegEx but after quite an extended research I can not find any advice as to how to do what I need neighter with PS itself nor was I able to find any RegEx instruction that would find the right lines and grab the words.

Preferred way would by to do it in PowerShell as I have already made plenty effort to make a script that would sort out the data in needed order.

Comment: Hi robert. please give an example of the source data, the desired output,  and your current "polluted" output. format it using ``` blocks

Comment: With "Those words do not really have any properties that would distinguish them among other words except for the number of the line where each o the word is located"...does that mean that they are the 6th line?

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, the "messy" file is on the desktop, named `website.txt`.
The output is on the Desktop as well, named `meds.txt`

```
# first, load up txt file
$website = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\website.txt";
# match all lines that start with a capital character, then have between 3 and 50 lowercase characters, and end with a space followed by a 2 digit number.
#create a () capture group that only contains the name of the medication, without the number
$matches = ($website | Select-String  -CaseSensitive  -Pattern '^([A-Z][a-z]{3,50}) \d{2}$').Matches;

# go over each match and extract the capture group out of it
# append each match to array

$medications = foreach ($match in $matches){    
    $match.Groups[1].Value;
}

# write array to file
$medications | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\meds.txt"
```

---

In the comments I meant *edit* your current question, not add comments as answers.

Note: the expression used to capture the medicine names is based on your dataset. It won't catch any medications with spaces or with capital letters (other than the 1st letter) in their name.
changing it shouldn't be too difficult, see [this](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/finiteautomata/Section07/sect07_11.html)

Answer (score 0):

They words all seem to be on the sixth line without any empty lines in between for:

> Those words do not really have any properties that would distingush
> them among other words except for the number of the line where each o
> the word is located.

In that case, you you could the whole file with `-Raw`:

```
(?:\A|\r?\n\r?\n)\S.*(?:\r?\n(\S.*)){5}
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\A|\r?\n\r?\n)` Assert the start of the string or match 2 newlines
- `\S.*` Match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(\S.*)){5}` Repeat 5 lines starting with a non whitespace char and capture the last occurrence in **group 1**

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tiXnFR/1).

Example

```
$path = Resolve-Path "unsoted.txt" | Select -Expand Path
$data = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw
$pattern = "(?:\A|\r?\n\r?\n)\S.*(?:\r?\n(\S.*)){5}"
[regex]::Matches($data, $pattern).ForEach{ $_.Groups[1] }.Value | Out-File medications.txt
```

Output

```
Amoxicillin 6
Clindamycin 17
Azithromycin 28
```

---

If the name of the medicine should start for example with an uppercase char A-Z and a lowercase char a-z, you could make the pattern a bit more specific like:

```
(?:\A|\r?\n\r?\n)\S.*(?:\r?\n\S.*){4}\r?\n([A-Z][a-z].*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t0MfBN/1)